# set value of next dropdown on changing previous dropdown

Tags: jquery, ajax

When I select any even dropdown, then value of next dropdown will be same as I selected for previous dropdown. For example, when I change 2nd dropdown, the value of 3rd dropdown will be same as 2nd dropdown

```js
$('#FinancialDataTable td:nth-child(2n)').find('select').on('change', function() {
  var abc = $(this).next("input:first").val();
  alert(abc);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="FinancialDataTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>From</th>
      <th>To</th>
      <th>Weight (In KG)</th>
      <th>Rate (Rate Per KG)</th>
      <th><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary addOption" value="Add Row"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control select2 from" style="width:100%;" name="from[]" required="">
          <option value="">Seller Firm</option>
          <option value="2">XYZ</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control select2 to" style="width:100%;" name="to[]" required="">
          <option value="">Select Purchaser Firm</option>
          <option value="1">Nugen Feeds</option>
          <option value="4">Vasu &amp; Sons</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="number" class="form-control weight" name="weight[]" required=""></td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control rate" name="rate[]" required=""></td>
      <td> <button class="btn btn-primary removeOption">Remove Rule</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control select2 from" style="width:100%;" name="from[]" required="">
          <option value="0">Select Seller Firm</option>
          <option value="1">Nugen Feeds</option>
          <option value="4">Vasu &amp; Sons</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control select2 to" style="width:100%;" name="to[]" required="">
          <option value="">Select Purchaser Firm</option>
          <option value="1">Nugen Feeds</option>
          <option value="4">Vasu &amp; Sons</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="number" class="form-control weight" name="weight[]" required=""></td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control rate" name="rate[]" required=""></td>
      <td> <button class="btn btn-primary removeOption">Remove Rule</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control select2 from" style="width:100%;" name="from[]" required="">
          <option value="0">Select Seller Firm</option>
          <option value="1">Nugen Feeds</option>
          <option value="4">Vasu &amp; Sons</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control select2 to" style="width:100%;" name="to[]" required="">
          <option value="">Select Purchaser Firm</option>
          <option value="1">Nugen Feeds</option>
          <option value="4">Vasu &amp; Sons</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="number" class="form-control weight" name="weight[]" required=""></td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control rate" name="rate[]" required=""></td>
      <td> <button class="btn btn-primary removeOption">Remove Rule</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control select2 from" style="width:100%;" name="from[]" required="">
          <option value="0">Select Seller Firm</option>
          <option value="1">Nugen Feeds</option>
          <option value="4">Vasu &amp; Sons</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control select2 to" style="width:100%;" name="to[]" required="">
          <option value="">Seller Firm</option>
          <option value="3">ABC</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="number" class="form-control weight" name="weight[]" required=""></td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control rate" name="rate[]" required=""></td>
      <td> <button class="btn btn-primary removeOption">Remove Rule</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is you want vertically dropdown change and reflect next or Horizontally dropdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Raeesh Alam

I got my answer with the help of your answer. I edited my code to following snippet.

```
$(document).on('change', '#FinancialDataTable td:nth-child(2n) select', function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().next().find('td:nth-child(2n+1) select').val($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check below snippet I hope this will help you lot.

```js
// Change in 1st column also reflect in 2nd column
$(document).on('change', '#FinancialDataTable td:nth-child(1) select', function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().find('td:nth-child(2) select').val($(this).val());
});
// Change in 2nd column also reflect in 1st column
$(document).on('change', '#FinancialDataTable td:nth-child(2) select', function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().find('td:nth-child(1) select').val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid my-2">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <table id="FinancialDataTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>From</th>
            <th>To</th>
            <th>Weight (In KG)</th>
            <th>Rate (Rate Per KG)</th>
            <th><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary addOption" value="Add Row"></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <select class="form-control select2 from" style="width:100%;" name="from[]" required="">
                <option value="0">Select Seller Firm</option>
                <option value="1">Nugen Feeds</option>
                <option value="4">Vasu &amp; Sons</option>
              </select>
            </td>
            <td>
              <select class="form-control select2 to" style="width:100%;" name="to[]" required="">
                <option value="0">Select Purchaser Firm</option>
                <option value="1">Nugen Feeds</option>
                <option value="4">Vasu &amp; Sons</option>
              </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="number" class="form-control weight" name="weight[]" required=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control rate" name="rate[]" required=""></td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-primary removeOption">Remove Rule</button></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <select class="form-control select2 from" style="width:100%;" name="from[]" required="">
                <option value="0">Select Seller Firm</option>
                <option value="1">Nugen Feeds</option>
                <option value="4">Vasu &amp; Sons</option>
              </select>
            </td>
            <td>
              <select class="form-control select2 to" style="width:100%;" name="to[]" required="">
                <option value="0">Select Purchaser Firm</option>
                <option value="1">Nugen Feeds</option>
                <option value="4">Vasu &amp; Sons</option>
              </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="number" class="form-control weight" name="weight[]" required=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control rate" name="rate[]" required=""></td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-primary removeOption">Remove Rule</button></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <select class="form-control select2 from" style="width:100%;" name="from[]" required="">
                <option value="0">Select Seller Firm</option>
                <option value="1">Nugen Feeds</option>
                <option value="4">Vasu &amp; Sons</option>
              </select>
            </td>
            <td>
              <select class="form-control select2 to" style="width:100%;" name="to[]" required="">
                <option value="0">Select Purchaser Firm</option>
                <option value="1">Nugen Feeds</option>
                <option value="4">Vasu &amp; Sons</option>
              </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="number" class="form-control weight" name="weight[]" required=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control rate" name="rate[]" required=""></td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-primary removeOption">Remove Rule</button></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <select class="form-control select2 from" style="width:100%;" name="from[]" required="">
                <option value="0">Select Seller Firm</option>
                <option value="1">Nugen Feeds</option>
                <option value="4">Vasu &amp; Sons</option>
              </select>
            </td>
            <td>
              <select class="form-control select2 to" style="width:100%;" name="to[]" required="">
                <option value="0">Select Purchaser Firm</option>
                <option value="1">Nugen Feeds</option>
                <option value="4">Vasu &amp; Sons</option>
              </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="number" class="form-control weight" name="weight[]" required=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control rate" name="rate[]" required=""></td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-primary removeOption">Remove Rule</button></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but actually what I want is, when I change first TO Column then from column in next row should change to same value as To column have in first column. This should be dynamically for all elements. Means, When I change any TO Column, then next from column should change